# How to measure High Availability in Google cloud Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, data-warehouse, google-cloud-dataproc

As per the google docs , measuring High Availability of Dataproc  based on HDFS & YARN availability not based on regions/zones . Is it possible to keep one master in one zone & another in different zone to get HA in context to Location ?
Also please elaborate , whether configuring Dataproc cluster in Global Endpoint achieve HA in context to location ?

I have already gone through Google docs but that doesn't clear above doubts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dataproc HA does not guarantee regional availability, because all Dataproc cluster nodes should be in the same GCP zone.

To achieve regional availability you need to create Dataproc clusters in multiple zones and use [Dataproc Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview) with label-based [cluster selectors](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/cluster-selectors) to distribute job submission across zonal clusters.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a cloud function to instantiate Dataproc WorkflowTemplate based on logs ?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, you need to use Dataproc API from Cloud Function to achieve this: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.workflowTemplates/instantiate